# Nautilus randomly starts eating all my RAM until computer crashes

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, ram

Title says it all. I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 18.04 (alongside Win10) on a MSI GS65.

I've randomly gotten this problem over the past month or so, but I just got it now twice back to back when downloading a ~2gb zip file and using text editor (unconnected but somewhat atypical activities, which is why I mention them). Coincidence? Other than this incident, I haven't identified any particular computing activities that cause Nautilus to go haywire.

I know Nautilus is the problem because I checked `top` in the terminal. It also starts using all my CPU power, but the crash seems to be caused by using all the RAM, and then the swap.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

EDIT: I just got the problem again now after submitting the question! I wasn't using texteditor or downloading anything, or really doing anything intensive. I was able to stop the problem by doing `killall nautilus`, but I don't see that as a good long-term solution....

EDIT 2: I see that nautilus is the file manager for Ubuntu. I don't think I was doing anything heavy duty (moving or copying files) just now, so not sure why Nautilus would lose its mind....

EDIT 3: Here's the output to RJ's question:

```
drussellmrichie@russells-gs65:~
$ find /home -user root 
/home
/home/drussellmrichie/.dbus
find: ‘/home/drussellmrichie/.dbus’: Permission denied
/home/drussellmrichie/.cache/dconf
find: ‘/home/drussellmrichie/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
/home/drussellmrichie/.ssh/known_hosts
drussellmrichie@russells-gs65:~
$ sudo find /home -user root 
[sudo] password for drussellmrichie: 
/home
/home/drussellmrichie/.dbus
/home/drussellmrichie/.dbus/session-bus
/home/drussellmrichie/.dbus/session-bus/b5f842e2762d4169bd58142b38eee016-0
/home/drussellmrichie/.dbus/session-bus/b5f842e2762d4169bd58142b38eee016-1
/home/drussellmrichie/.cache/dconf
/home/drussellmrichie/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Can you specify what your do after you downloaded the large zip file? Typically, downloading does not involve nautilus. Probably, you then open that zip file in nautilus? Describe sharply what you dit to trigger the crash: that would allow us to try reproducing this issue.

Comment: I was in the middle of downloading the zip file when nautilus went haywire -- I never had a chance to unzip it.

Comment: Then the downloading in its own right will not have been the cause of the nautilus crash. Did some testing for a while (doing searches, creating and opening large archives, etc) and I bumped nautilus memory usage up to 53 MB. With only thehome folder open and no activity for 15 minutes, the memory allocation remains so high. nautilus does not release used memory, which qualifies as a leak. However, for me, the extent of the leak is not at all problematic.

Answer (score 3):

The case where nautilus uses extreme RAM to make your system crash is very extreme, but I recently found that nautilus indeed has memory leaks. You can easily test by opening system monitor, and opening some windows where you do some searching, or open large folders. Memory usage of nautilus grows, but the memory is never released when you close the windows. The memory is only released when you fully close nautilus.

I suspect you use icons on the desktop, which is the default on Ubuntu. That way, nautilus is never closed, so memory presumably keeps growing during the session. Typically, these memory leaks are relatively small, however, and normally not of (significant) practical concern.

I do not have an active desktop, i.e., no icons on the desktop. The benefit of that is that nautilus is closed when the last window is closed. Thus, it is less likely to build up memory use by nautilus during a session.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried opening a folder with ~10gb of files in it, and I didn't see memory usage budge? Also, my desktop is blank. When the problem arises, should I do `killall nautilus` or `nautilus -q` -- the latter is supposedly safer but I'm worried that it might sometimes take too long to close nautilus if it starts eating memory?

Comment: Should have posted my latest command here instead of above ;) Both commands should be equally safe. By default, killall gives a gentle SIGTERM signal, which would tell nautilus to please close down.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, if the problem is to remain mysterious, then I guess I will have to be satisfied with just killing nautilus when it starts eating memory.....Thanks for your help.

Comment: It may be something specific on your system, because I do not find similar reports on nautilus.

Comment: I had this recently. Nautilus was using approx 2Gb memory. I had left open the ~/.cache/friends/avatars folder from an old Ubuntu system. It had 16,000 thumbnail sized images in it. Closing that folder window released the memory after a short delay.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this in past where you have some directories under /home not owned by the same user.

Run something like this to find out.

```
find /home -user root
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the output in my question. Doesn't seem like I have other directories under /home that aren't mine?

Comment: Of course you do, it seems you use sudo inappropriately. Probably not the cause of current issue but then again.. You should remove all root owned files in your home dir. (- Do you have a huge number of video or image files..

Comment: Your update shows the `/home/drussellmrichie/.dbus`, `/home/drussellmrichie/.cache/dconf and `/home/drussellmrichie/.ssh/known_hosts` are not owned by your user name, and that tells me you have run dconf editor using sudo at one point. Run chown -R yourusername:yourgroup on those three directories and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I ran `chown -R drussellmrichie` on each of those paths. I didn't specify a group, since this is just my personal laptop?

Comment: Okay, even after running the above terminal commands, I've now determined that simply opening text editor is one circumstance that causes my memory to be eaten up (until I kill nautilus)! Weird! I see a few old posts about memory leaks in text editor, but nothing very recent that looks relevant. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to match ownership with the rest of your home directory. If you don't that may cause unexpected behavior. It is important that all home directories to be owned by your username:usergroup. That's probably why you are seeing random stuff causing memory problems.